# Снять образ с флешки в системе Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iso, dd

Требуется создать образ iso с загрузочной флешки. Система Ubuntu 18.04 Пробовал использовать утилиту dd . Получается образ соответствующий физическому размеру носителя. Оно и понятно, считывает как блочное устройство побайтово. 
Но меня это не устраивает, т.к. файлы занимают несколько сотен мегабайт, а носитель несколько гигов. Нужно чтоб был такой образ, который создался бы как через утилиту Ultraiso в windows.
Архивацию dd просьба не предлагать.
Поиск мануалов в интернете к успехам не привели. Я даже не думал, что это вызовет такую сложность на линуксе. В windows такие вопросы решаются элементарно.

Comment: Как вы делаете образ флешки с ultraiso, что у вас получаются мегабайты? Я сейчас сделал образ 32ГБ флешки функцией «Создать образ жесткого диска» — получился ровно 32ГБ образ, точно такой же как сделал бы dd. Хотя файлов на флешке было меньше гигабайта.

Comment: что ж там архивировать нужно такого? может лучше tar?

Comment: то, что вы желаете, называется не «снять образ» (что и делается программой cp, и, кстати, программа dd тут нужна как микроскоп для забивания гвоздей), а «создать новый». довольно примитивная процедура, стопицотмильонов раз описанная в этих ваших интернетах: google://создать+iso+образ+из+файлов

Answer (score 0):

> Требуется создать образ iso с загрузочной флешки.

1. Скопируйте все файлы с Вашей флэшки в любое место на HDD
2. Запустите программу Brasero (она, как правило, по дефаульту установлена)
3. Скажите ей, что желаете создать ISO образ и укажите откуда брать образ флэшки.
4. Укажите, куда поместить ISO
5. Нажмите кнопку " Создать образ"

Comment: Вы забыли скопировать загрузчик, который в MBR не является файлом.

Comment: А его и не копируют. Насколько я помню, там должна быть галка типа "Сделать диск загрузочным", но это уже не во время создания ISO, а при прожиге диска.

Comment: Без правильного загрузчика диск не загрузится, копировать его (или каким-то образом воссоздавать такой, чтобы он умел грузить скопированные файлы) нужно обязательно