# Создание образа/снимка флешки без пустых блоков в linux (debian/ubuntu)

Tags: linux, резервное-копирование, dd

Необходимо создать полный образ флешки flash.img, но без пустых блоков. Флешка содержит несколько разделов.
Создаю через утилиту dd - создаётся весь снимок флешки её же размера (хотя информации 1/4 всего объёма флешки).

В дальнейшем образ должен быть записан на любой носитель со всеми размеченными разделами через win32imageWriter или balenaEtcher, либо через ту же dd в линуксе.

Comment: Если это надо для уменьшения размера образа, то предварительно забейте пустое место на флешке нулями, а результирующий образ сожмите. Нули сжимаются хорошо. Если же описанное — самоцель, то, увы, или "полный образ", или "без пустых блоков".

Comment: @Alexander Prokoshev, суть в том, что флешка 16 Гб, на ней информации 4 гб. Если я захочу записать этот образ на флешку 8 Гб - утилита dd выдаёт ошибку плана "не могу записать, т.к. образ большего размера, чем флешка". Уже сталкивался с такой ситуацией, когда временно переносил серверок под linux на жёсткий диск меньшего размера

Comment: fsarchiver? Возможно, clonezilla? Второе не совсем "в linux", но...

Comment: А зачем образ флешки нужен? Может просто скопировать файлы?

Comment: @eri, для того чтобы можно было другому человеку img образ через программу типа balena или win32diskImager сразу записать на флешку

Comment: Уменьшай раздел через дисковую утилиту до минимального размера. До 8 гб. Dd отрезай эти 8 гб через параметры bs=10M и count=810

Comment: [дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1089008/178576)

Comment: @aleksandr barakin, ответы на "дубликат" не решают мою задачу

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, в каком месте клонзилла не совсем линукс?

Comment: @donRumata в контексте этого конкретного вопроса — в том, что его автору надо в ту клонзиллу из своего линукса перезагружаться. Соответственно он не будет находиться в том линуксе (debian/ubuntu), который подразумевал.

Comment: И это даст изоляцию от той кучи прог, настроек и работающих процессов, которые возможно мешают ему сделать задуманное. А вообще - можно попробовать `gddrescue` и `partclone`, которые есть в клонзилле и так.

Comment: Удивительно, неужели ни один из комментирующих здесь не слышал слов sparse-образ?